# Transfer time at Oslo OSL Airport

Tags: airport-transfer, norway, oslo

**TL;DR: Is a 1h20m transfer time enough for a EU citizen at Oslo (OSL) airport?**

I'm looking into buying plane tickets to Norway with a transfer in Oslo.

- The flight will be Munich(MUC) ➡ Oslo(OSL) ➡ Tromsø (TOS).
- Both flights will be operated by the same airline (SAS)
- I'm a EU citizen
- I will have check-in baggage

The connection gets offered this way by the airline directly but another connections with the same first flight but a 2h transfer time is also offered.

My experience in flying showed that transfer times vary greatly depending on airport and country (From 15 minutes to hours).

Additionally: Will I go trough customs in Oslo or Tromsø?

Comment: I doubt it makes a huge difference, but two things are missing from your question which are potentially relevant: a) which airline will you fly with? b) will you have checked baggage?

Comment: If you book the short connection and by some colossal fluke don't make the connection, you would most likely be rebooked on the later flight to Tromsø anyway. (Or if that happens to be full, a later one that day -- SAS alone flies the route ten times a day).

Comment: @ChrisH The airline is SAS(already in the quesiton) and I will have echecked baggage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough time if your first flight is on time.

You will go through customs in Oslo. The [procedure](https://youtu.be/L1jP_0PsgEU) is a bit unusual.

Answer (score 1):

It’s is more than adequate for sure if you only have carry on and more than likely ok even with checked baggage, Oslo’s airport is really small